# Adding Custom "trace id with Alpha numeric values and spiting it out in application Log "

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using  Sleuth 2.1.3.
I want  to add  a custom "trace  ID" as "correlation id" with alpha numeric  value and want to spit in logs  with  spanid  and  parent id.
If i use below implementation for creating new custom trace id. does it  get  printed in logs ?

I tried  below implementation   but   does not see any custom trace in log 
https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin-aws/blob/release-0.11.2/brave-propagation-aws/src/main/java/brave/propagation/aws/AWSPropagation.java

```
Tracing.newBuilder().propagationFactory(
  ExtraFieldPropagation.newFactoryBuilder(B3Propagation.FACTORY)
                       .addField("x-vcap-request-id")
                       .addPrefixedFields("x-baggage-", Arrays.asList("country-code", "user-id"))
                       .build()
);
```

I tried with above code  from https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/reference/html/#propagation but didnt see any custom trace id in log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've passed in the `B3Propagation.FACTORY` as the implementation of the propagation factory so you're explicitly stating that you want the default B3 headers. You've said that you want some other field that is alphanumeric to be also propagated. Then in a log parsing tool you can define that you want to use your custom field as the trace id, but it doesn't mean that the deafult X-B3-TraceId field will be changed. If you want to use your custom field as trace id that Sleuth understands, you need to change the logging format and implement a different propagation factory bean.

Answer (score 0):

One  of the  way which   worked for me is 
using ExtraFieldPropagation
and adding those   keys in sleuth  properties  under   propagation-keys
and  whitelisted-keys

sample code 
  '  @Autowired Tracer tracer;

```
Span currentSpan = tracer.nextSpan().start();
ExtraFieldPropagation.set(
      "customkey", "customvalue");
sleuth:
    log:
      slf4j:
        whitelisted-mdc-key : customkey
propagation:
      tag:
        enabled: true
    propagation-keys : customkey '
```